# How can I easily access data both inside and outside a container?

Tags: docker

I have a docker container with MinGW compiler set up inside it. I want to use it for development. That is I want to compile, test, edit, compile, test ...

The container will also be used in the CI pipeline, and eventually for producing production builds. By using the same container we ensure consistency in the build environment.

My host has my development tools for code editing etc. while the container has the compiler, so clearly the files need to be shared.

I have set up a volume. Unfortunately I cannot access it with my user account:

```
# ls -lAFd /var/lib/docker
drwx--x--x 11 root docker 4096 Jul  4 09:11 /var/lib/docker/
# ls -lAFd /var/lib/docker/volumes/mingw_build/_data
drwxr-xr-x 6 alastair docker 4096 Jul  3 14:31 /var/lib/docker/volumes/mingw_build/_data/
```

My user is in group docker but group docker does NOT have read permissions on /var/lib/docker and so cannot access the _data directory of the volume.

I have tried cheating and using sudo to tweak the folder permissions so that group docker has read permissions all the way down the path, but those permissions get rewritten on reboot - no doubt when the docker server starts.

Can anyone figure out a way around this? I have tried using symlinks, but they always inherit the most restrictive permissions of the path elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I originally read the documentation it looked like only named volumes can be used, but I have just found out that directories can also be used as the source. E.g.:

```
mkdir /home/alastair/mingw_build
docker run -v /home/alastair/mingw_build:/home/mingw_build/build mingw_build
```

Since I want to use the same container and run script for CI testing as for local development, I set an environment variable in my .bashrc, and test for it in my run script. If it is present I use the directory it points to, and if not I use a named container, creating it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Docker includes a user/group remapping feature - based on user namespaces - that is not enabled by default.

Enable "userne-remap" on the docker daemon by following instructions there : https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/

Comment: That looks like  a possibility, but the namespaced directory is still under /var/lib/docker so may still be inaccessible. I will try it out when I get a chance.

Comment: After creating /etc/docker/daemon.json (it didn't previously exist) with the configuration specified in the article you linked, the docker service kept failing to start. Delete the file and all is well.

Comment: What is your current docker version?

Comment: Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87.

Comment: Did you add your user to docker group ? `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`

Comment: Yes, as I said in the question, "My user is in group docker".